# Django, query_set annotation with conditional expression

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    expiry_date = models.DateField()
```

How can I build a query which fetches all documents and give them annotation whether the expiry date has passed or not?
I tried this:

```
today = timezone.now.date()

Document.objects.annotate(
    expired=Value(
        F('expiry_date')<today, 
        BooleanField()
    )
)
```

But it raises an error: `TypeError: unorderable types: F() < datetime.date()`
How can I compare value from `F()` expression with the date?

Also, I'd like to avoid SQL and `.extra()`

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do that in the database. Put it in a model method:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    expiry_date = models.DateField()

    def expired(self):
        return self.expiry_date < timezone.now.date()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.expiry_date`

Comment: I need to do it in the queryset because later I want to be able to call `.order_by('expired')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional annotation.

Tested with `Django 1.11.10`.

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, When  
from django.utils import timezone

Document.objects.annotate(
    expired=Case(
        When(expiry_date__lt=timezone.now(), then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).order_by('expired')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Django >= 2, didn't check for previous versions

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Document.objects.annotate(
    expired=ExpressionWrapper(Q(expiry_date__lt=Now()),
    output_field=models.BooleanField())
)
```

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57114224/11193405