# how can i add an expiration date function on a model?

Tags: django, django-models

i am trying to make a key verification app that when accepted it would create the same app on the user's profile, so i have done everything but i have struggled making the expiration date part, i want the expired boolean become true when the date is expired, but i have no idea on how to implement it

```
#models.py
    class ProductKey(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        unique=False)
        key = models.CharField(max_length=14)
        valid_from = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        valid_to = models.DateTimeField()
        expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: You don't need a field for this, you handle it in logic when the `valid_to` date has expired

Answer (score 2):

Please do *not* add a database field for this. You will introduce data duplication: if you later set the `valid_to`, you will have to update `expred` as well, so the logic would introduce extra challenges.

You can annotate your `ProductKey` model, such that objects that arise from this have an attribute `expired`:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

ProductKey.objects.annotate(
    expired=ExpressionWrapper(Q(valid_to__lt=Now()), output_field=BooleanField())
)
```

You can then filter on that property. For example you can retrieve the `ProductKey`s that are expired with:

```
ProductKey.objects.annotate(
    expired=ExpressionWrapper(Q(valid_to__lt=Now()), output_field=BooleanField())
).filter(expired=True)
```

If you need this often, you can annotate this in the manager, like:

```
class ExpiredManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            expired=ExpressionWrapper(Q(valid_to__lt=Now()), output_field=BooleanField())
        )

class ProductKey(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    unique=False)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = ExpiredManager()
```

Comment: but this will only filter the ProductKeys that are expired, who can i use this info to turn the expired boolean of the Productkey model into True ?, if my question seems stupid paradon me and explain it to me since currently am just a newbie.

Comment: @rector: you do *not* store a boolean field. This is bad design. You thus make an annotate such that the query returns a `.expired` attribute. If you would add a field, it would make synchronizing much harder.

Comment: oh i see, and so do i need to place this peace of code in the models.py outside the class and then it would appear in my admin panel with just making these changes ?

Comment: @rector: if you specify the `queryset = ProductKey.objects.all()` with the manager, or `queryset = ProductKey.objects.annotate(...)` without the manager in your `ModelAdmin`, yes.

Comment: and how can i add this queryset into the admin panel of this model ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods) for this use case and calculate that on the fly.

```
@property
def expired(self):
   # calculate here if its still valid
```